# EWS Contact, check email address key

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

So the app I am working on pulls a specific outlook contact and displays the props.  The issue I am running into is if the email address field is present becuase a contact may not have an email address and I need to check for this.  The error message that is being returned is {"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}.

Below is the code.  So it's complaning that the email address key is not present so it cannot assign it.  So how do i check if the email key is present prior to the assignment?

`EWSForm.EmailAddresses = Contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Address;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since EmailAddresses is of type EmailAddressDictionary and from the MSDN documentation:

```
public sealed class EmailAddressDictionary : DictionaryProperty<EmailAddressKey,EmailAddressEntry>
```

You should be able to do this (Use the `Contains(Key)` method as defined here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634144(v=exchg.80).aspx):

```
    if(   
        Contact.EmailAddresses.
            Contains( EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1 ) 
        ) {
            EWSForm.EmailAddresses = 
                Contact.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Address;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively use `TryGetValue()` which will not throw an exception, instead it returns a boolean to indicate whether it was able to return a value with the key.

```
EmailAddress email;
var success = contact.EmailAddresses.TryGetVaue(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, out email);

if (success)
{
    // Use email for task
    SendMail(email.Address);
}
```